# Is Interceptor.Chain.proceed() a Thread Blocking Method?

Tags: android, okhttp

Suppose I create my own implementation of an `Interceptor` from OkHttp3:

```kotlin
class MyInterceptor: Interceptor {

    private val gson = Gson()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        // Will this block the main thread?
        val response = chain.proceed(request)

        return Response.Builder()
            .code(200)
            .request(request)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .message("OK")
            .body(
                gson.toJson("foo").toResponseBody("application/json".toMediaType())
            )
            .build()
    }
}
```

Will the call to `chain.proceed()` block the main thread? This seems counter-intuitive to what is provided Retrofit's support of `suspend` functions, which is built on top of OkHttp3. Because I've chosen to use an interceptor, do I now lose that async support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the call to chain.proceed() block the main thread?

It will block whatever thread `intercept()` was called on. If that is the main application thread, you will have other problems (e.g., `NetworkOnMainThreadException`), and that situation is unrelated to whether or not you have this interceptor.

> Because I've chosen to use an interceptor, do I now lose that async support?

No. This is all operating underneath that async support. If this OkHttp request was kicked off by a Retrofit `suspend` API, then `intercept()` should be called on a background thread (whichever one OkHttp/Retrofit is using from its thread pool).

Comment: I see, very good! And I'd imagine that the async support also applies if this was done using callbacks? Such as through OkHttp3's `Call.enqueue()`

Comment: @coolDudeL: "And I'd imagine that the async support also applies if this was done using callbacks?" -- yes.